# Python optparse is not able to parse the `$` symbol

Tags: python, optparse

if I am using a `$` symbol in the arguments, `python optparse` is not able to parse it properly. It just ignores the symbol and the next character. If I am giving a `\` before `$` then it is working fine. But I don't want to give a `\`. Please help me out how to overcome this situation.

Its happening only in Linux; on Windows it is working fine.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: The Unix shell won't allow `$` in arguments.  Please provide the code and the command line that won't parse.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this happens because Linux uses $ to identify shell variables.

So, if you want to use this symbole in your arguments, your only chance is to pass '\$', that won't be replaced by the invoking shell. Windows uses %variablename% to identify that kind of variables, that's why you don't experience this kind of "problem" on that O.S.

Comment: OP may verify that it's not his script or the Linux python implementation that's at fault by invoking his script from _another_ python script with the `subprocess` module. Then shell expansion will not be performed on the arguments. Like this: `subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/script.py", "$arg1", "arg$2", "etc."]).communicate()`

Comment: Well.. Not your _only_ chance. You can also wrap each argument in single quotes. That way, you can have space, line break and almost everything else in your argument. For example: echo '$hey, $you'

Comment: Reading your answer again, it looks like you both wrap your argument in single quotes AND use a backslash. You should only use one of them.